# Magento2 one page optimization

Tags: magento2, seo, product-page, page, optimization

How do modify the header to make sure that all the relevant information is display to google?

When i google **Magento2 SEO** page optimization, all I see is performance related thread nothing related to one page optimization . I would like to do some **one page SEO** optimization - when I see how google see my page. The first few things google sees as follow:

Skip to Content,

Sign In,

Create an Account, Toggle Nav XXXX, My Cart, Search, Advanced Search, Search, Compare Products.

Answer (score 0):

For That You Have to Manage Three Things

- Create descriptive page titles
- Create good meta descriptions
- Prevent search engines from displaying DMOZ data in search results
  for your site

**Create descriptive page titles**

- As explained above, make sure every page on your site has a title
  specified in the  tag. If you’ve got a large site and are
  concerned you may have forgotten a title somewhere, the HTML
  suggestions page in Search Console lists missing or potentially
  problematic `<title>` tags on your site.
- Page titles should be descriptive and concise. Avoid vague
  descriptors like "Home" for your home page, or "Profile" for a
  specific person's profile. Also avoid unnecessarily long or verbose
  titles, which are likely to get truncated when they show up in the
  search results.
- Avoid keyword stuffing. It's sometimes helpful to have a few
  descriptive terms in the title, but there’s no reason to have the
  same words or phrases appear multiple times. A title like "`Foobar,
  foo bar, foobars, foo bars`" doesn't help the user, and this kind of
  keyword stuffing can make your results look spammy to Google and to
  users.
- Be careful about disallowing search engines from crawling your pages.
  Using the `robots.txt` protocol on your site can stop Google from
  crawling your pages, but it may not always prevent them from being
  indexed. For example, Google may index your page if we discover it by
  following a link from someone else's site. To display it in search
  results, Google will need to display a title of some kind and because
  we won't have access to any of your page content, we will rely on
  off-page content such as anchor text from other sites. (To truly
  block a URL from being indexed, you can use meta tags.)

**Create good meta descriptions**

- Make sure that every page on your site has a meta description. The
  HTML suggestions page in Search Console lists pages where Google has
  detected missing or problematic meta descriptions.
- Differentiate the descriptions for different pages. Identical or
  similar descriptions on every page of a site aren't helpful when
  individual pages appear in the web results. In these cases we're less
  likely to display the boilerplate text. Wherever possible, create
  descriptions that accurately describe the specific page. Use
  site-level descriptions on the main home page or other aggregation
  pages, and use page-level descriptions everywhere else. If you don't
  have time to create a description for every single page, try to
  prioritize your content: At the very least, create a description for
  the critical URLs like your home page and popular pages.
- Include clearly tagged facts in the description. The meta description
  doesn't just have to be in sentence format; it's also a great place
  to include structured data about the page. For example, news or blog
  postings can list the author, date of publication, or byline
  information. This can give potential visitors very relevant
  information that might not be displayed in the snippet otherwise.
  Similarly, product pages might have the key bits of
  information—price, age, manufacturer—scattered throughout a page. A
  good meta description can bring all this data together. For example,
  the following meta description provides detailed information about a
  book.

**Prevent search engines from displaying DMOZ data in search results for your site**

- One source Google uses to generate snippets is the [Open Directory
  Project](http://www.dmoz.org/). You can direct us not to use this as a source by adding a
  meta tag to your pages.